# The foreign key connection field is queried twice

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, egg

I have two tables, one about articles and the other about comments

```
//this is the table model of articles
module.exports = (app) => {
    const { STRING, INTEGER, DATE } = app.Sequelize;

    const Model = app.model.define(
        "all_topics",
        {
            id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
            title: STRING(30),
            content: STRING,
            user_id: INTEGER,
            created_at: DATE,
            updated_at: DATE,
            tag: STRING(30),
        },
        {
            underscored: true,
        }
    );

    Model.associate = function () {
        Model.belongsTo(app.model.Users, { foreignKey: "user_id" });
        Model.hasMany(app.model.Comments, {
            foreignKey: "topic_id",
            sourceKey: "id",
        });
    };

    return Model;
};
```

```
//this is the table model of comments
module.exports = (app) => {
    const { STRING, INTEGER, DATE } = app.Sequelize;

    const Model = app.model.define(
        "comments",
        {
            id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
            topic_id: INTEGER,
            user_id: INTEGER,
            parent_id: INTEGER,
            content: STRING,
            created_at: DATE,
        },
        {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true,
            underscored: true,
        }
    );

    Model.associate = function () {
        Model.belongsTo(app.model.Users, {
            foreignKey: { user_id: "id", parent_id: "id" },
        });
        Model.belongsTo(app.model.AllTopics, {
            foreignKey: "topic_id",
            sourceKey: "id",
        });
    };

    return Model;
};
```

```
//Query the article that specifies the id and the comments it contains
const Service = require("egg").Service;

class TopicLoadService extends Service {
    async topicLoad(id) {
        const { ctx } = this;
        const topic = await ctx.model.AllTopics.findOne({
            where: {
                id,
            },
            include: [{ model: ctx.model.Comments }],
        });
        return { topic };
    }
}

module.exports = TopicLoadService;
```

Foreign keys have been set up in the MySQL database
But, an error was returned: Unknown column 'comments.userId' in 'field list'

The query statement it executes is

```
SELECT `all_topics`.`id`, 
       `all_topics`.`title`, 
       `all_topics`.`content`, 
       `all_topics`.`user_id`, 
       `all_topics`.`created_at`, 
       `all_topics`.`updated_at`, 
       `all_topics`.`tag`, 
       `comments`.`id` AS `comments.id`, 
       `comments`.`topic_id` AS `comments.topic_id`, 
       `comments`.`user_id` AS `comments.user_id`,       //Queried
       `comments`.`parent_id` AS `comments.parent_id`, 
       `comments`.`content` AS `comments.content`,     
       `comments`.`created_at` AS `comments.created_at`, 
       `comments`.`user_id` AS `comments.userId`       //Why is this another query?
FROM `all_topics` AS `all_topics` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` AS `comments` 
ON `all_topics`.`id` = `comments`.`topic_id` 
WHERE `all_topics`.`id` = '20000000';
```

I am a novice, some knowledge is not mastered, can you answer for me? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you include the definition of the comments table in your database?  For example, could you write a `CREATE TABLE comments ( ... );` statement and add it to the question?  That would make it much easier to troubleshoot this....

Comment: sorry, I'm using Navicat, so I didn't use statements.( To be precise, I can't create a table by statements, it's embarrassing ).The structure of table is same as the models above.

Comment: The foreign keys are ```CONSTRAINT com_user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id))```,```CONSTRAINT parent_id FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES users(id))```,```CONSTRAINT topic_id FOREIGN KEY(topic_id) REFERENCES all_topics(id))```. The foreign keys belong to comments table. Thank you

Comment: em...Actually, there is no error now. But，There are user_id and userId in the return results(Duplicate data ) If I don't set```underscored: true``` will report a mistake: "Unknown column 'comments.userId' in 'field list'"

Comment: That's okay Wei.  Even with Navicat, it should be possible to obtain a list of the columns in the `articles` and `comments` tables in you database, along with the datatype of each column.  If you can post the column names and their datatypes (or at least the ones that you are trying to map) in your question, it might be easier for someone to confirm that the `sequelize` definitions in your javascript correctly map your models to the database structures.

Comment: Actually, I just found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqsLXCcJl3Q&t=127s) on YouTube that shows how to export `create table` sql statements using Navicat.  It might help.

Comment: ```
CREATE TABLE `all_topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT)```

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `com_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`),
  ```

Comment: CONSTRAINT `com_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `topic_id` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`) REFERENCES `all_topics` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)

Comment: Thanks Wei.  Would you mind posting the table definitions in your original question?  You should be able to edit it and add them in.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points to note:

1. The `foreignKey` property usually takes a string representing the column name of the foreign key.  There's another property that's either called `sourceKey` or `targetKey`, depending on whether it's a `has` or `belongs` relationship lacking a junction table, that represents the referenced key.
2. `sequelize` usually has singular names for the names of the models, and constructs plural names for the names of tables in the database.  It's a good convention to follow, since the model instances will end up with helper methods like `Foo.addBar` and `Foo.addBars` for creating new child rows in the database.  See the [sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances) for more information.
3. There were some missing properties in the model definitions.  They might not be strictly necessary to get things working, but this way your models will more closely map to their corresponding structures in the database.

Try this:

```
// articles
module.exports = (app) => {
    const { STRING, INTEGER, DATE } = app.Sequelize;

    const Model = app.model.define(
        "all_topic", // Following sequelize convention, it might be better to have the model name be singular,
                     //  i.e. "all_topic", instead of "all_topics"....
        {
            id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
            title: { type: STRING(30), allowNull: false },
            content: { type: STRING, defaultValue: null },
            user_id: { type: INTEGER, references: { model: app.model.Users, key: 'id' }, allowNull: false },
            created_at: { type: DATE, defaultValue: null, allowNull: true },
            updated_at: { type: DATE, defaultValue: null, allowNull: true },
            tag: { type: STRING(30), allowNull: false },
        },
        {
            tableName: "all_topics",
            underscored: true
        }
    );

    Model.associate = function () {
        Model.belongsTo(app.model.Users, {
            foreignKey: "user_id",
            targetKey: "id",
            onDelete: "RESTRICT",
            onUpdate: "RESTRICT"
        });
        Model.hasMany(app.model.Comments, {
            foreignKey: "topic_id",
            sourceKey: "id",
            onDelete: "RESTRICT",
            onUpdate: "RESTRICT"
        });
    };

    return Model;
};
```

And for the comments model:

```
// comments
module.exports = (app) => {
    const { STRING, INTEGER, DATE } = app.Sequelize;

    const Model = app.model.define(
        "comment", // Following sequelize convention, it might be better to have the model name be singular,
                   //  i.e. "comment", instead of "comments"....
        {

            id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
            topic_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false },
            user_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false, references: { model: app.model.Users, key: 'id' } },
            parent_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false, references: { model: app.model.Users, key: 'id' } },
            topic_id: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: false, references: { model: app.model.AllTopics, key: 'id' } },
            content: { type: STRING, allowNull: false },
            created_at: { type: DATE, allowNull: false },
        },
        {
            timestamps: false
        }
    );

    Model.associate = function () {
        Model.belongsTo(app.model.Users, {
            foreignKey: "user_id",
            targetKey: "id",
            as: "user",
            onDelete: "RESTRICT",
            onUpdate: "RESTRICT"
        });
        Model.belongsTo(app.model.Users, {
            foreignKey: "parent_id",
            targetKey: "id",
            as: "parent",
            onDelete: "RESTRICT",
            onUpdate: "RESTRICT"
        });
        Model.belongsTo(app.model.AllTopics, {
            foreignKey: "topic_id",
            sourceKey: "id",
            onDelete: "RESTRICT",
            onUpdate: "RESTRICT"
        });
    };

    return Model;
};
```

Just a quick note about [sequelize timestamps](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#timestamps).  It is possible to enable timestamps and provide custom names for the columns.  According to the docs:

> It is also possible to enable only one of createdAt/updatedAt, and to
> provide a custom name for these columns:
>
> ```
> class Foo extends Model {}
> Foo.init({ /* attributes */ }, {  
>   sequelize,
>
>   // don't forget to enable timestamps!
>   timestamps: true,
>
>   // I don't want createdAt
>   createdAt: false,
>
>   // I want updatedAt to actually be called updateTimestamp  
>   updatedAt: 'updateTimestamp' });
> ```